# How to get links from table

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping

I would like to scrape only urls in "next matches" table from [this page](https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/russia/premier-league)

I used this code to scrape all urls:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='in-match']")
```

I tried to modify in this way

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[starts-with(@class, 'table-main')]/a[@class='in-match']")
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately I can't access that website right now, but if you can provide either a screenshot or a portion of the table html you are looking at then I might be able to help.

Comment: are you missing a `/` for `/a[@class='in-match']` so that it becomes `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[starts-with(@class, 'table-main')]//a[@class='in-match']")`? You can check out a similar question here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/34603/how-do-i-use-find-elements-by-xpath-to-only-get-some-elements-in-python-selenium

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
table/a
```

means that you want to locate *`anchor` node that is direct child of `table` node*. While you need to locate *`anchor` node that is descendant of `table` node*

Try

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[starts-with(@class, 'table-main')]//a[@class='in-match']")
```